# Add to add value to object inside an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have an array that contains 1 item.  It looks like this ...

```
[ { one: "one", two: "two" } ]
```

I want to add to the object so it how looks like this ...

```
[ { one: "one", two: "two", three: "three" } ]
```

how do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basic Javascrpt.

```
var array = [ { one: "one", two: "two" } ];


array[0].three = 'three';
```

means, `array` at index `0` set `three` to equal`"three"`

PS: this, nor are you using JSON

Comment: Thanks ...I didn't say it was JSON -- it isn't.  You're right, basic Javascript.  I'm trying to learn Javascript, Node, Mongo at the same time and am confusing myself on simple operations.

Comment: Ah ... I see where the JSON comment came from --- the title.  I was thinking it was JSON until I actually typed it out and realized it was just an object literal.